# SSH into linux after creating an access point with hostapd

Tags: ssh, remote-access, raspberry-pi, remote-server

I made a remote control vehicle with a Raspberry Pi, but i am linked to a wifi router. I decided to make the Pi itself some kind of router to connect directly to it. I downloaded and set up hostapd, set the own_ip_addr=127.0.0.1. When i ping 127.0.0.1, i get responses, but i can't ssh at that address. 
Any help is welcome. If you have any idea other than hostapd, please tell me. I just want to control the Pi via wifi without a router.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`127.0.0.1` is the local address, and not valid external to the Pi...

If you want to connect to the Pi externally, you must find the Pi's network IP.
You could find this by running `ip addr show` on the Pi, and taking note of the IP for the interface you are using.

Then just use that IP when you try SSHing.

Comment: I want to connect to the Pi from within the created network. I can connect but it will not accept ssh for some reason.

Comment: @Bogdan in that case, post the output of ssh with the `-v` flag, so we can see the error.